# Are there any phrases or idioms to describe someone rejected the chance to do something at first, but liked it the moment they tried it?

Tags: phrase-requests

Sometimes I use "I told you so" to express similar meaning, but this is more often used in the scenario where someone didn't listen to another's warning, not the other way around. I want to know if there's any expression for this?

Example: Peter has never played football before. John told him it's fun a lot of times, but he rejected that and said it's a stupid game. But he accidentally joined a football match one day and immediately fell in love with it.

Are there any other phrases or idioms that John can say to Peter?

Comment: I'm more interested in how someone _accidentally_ joins a football match.

Comment: @KillingTime you might have thought it was a scrabble match or something.

Comment: 'Don't knock it till you've tried it' is ballpark.

Comment: @Justin Ballpark is close but no cigar. This advice is "Why don't you give it a go!" not "I told you you'd like it / We told them they'd like it", and OP has asked for the latter. // "_See!_" is closer, but too short to offer on ELU.

Answer (score 5):

> Watching the movie after initially disliking it, I immediately **came to appreciate**
> its greatness.
>
> Watching the movie after initially disliking it, it's greatness immediately **grew on me**.

From The Free Dictionary:

> [**appreciate**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/appreciate): to
> recognize the quality, significance, or magnitude of
>
> [**grow on**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/grow+on): to become
> increasingly liked or appreciated by you

You could also say -

- *You can [come round](https://www.google.com/search?safe=strict&ei=-KaQXYeZOsPez7sP-K2bmAg&q=come+round&oq=come+round&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0l10.91081.93118..93322...0.1..0.206.1330.0j9j1....2..0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i273j0i131j0i67.zvPmmJC6Um4&ved=0ahUKEwiH9bC-h_bkAhVD73MBHfjWBoMQ4dUDCAs&uact=5) to their point of view (i.e. change your opinion).*
- *You can also [take a shine](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/take+a+shine+to) to something (not just people).*

Comment: Always the classic, *It grew on me ... Like a fungus!*

Answer (score 1):

**to blossom forth** [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/blossom) an idiom

> - Lit. [for a plant] to burst into flower. All the trees blossomed    forth at the same time. Each spring my tulips blossom forth in all
>     their glory.

- > Fig. **[for someone or a concept] to develop or grow quickly.**

As in:

> He accidentally joined a football match one day and his interest in
>   the game blossomed forth.

And for John's reply to the event unfolding:

> John says to Peter:  So, I see your interest in football has blossomed.

Comment: This doesn't carry any sort of implication about initial rejection.

Answer (score 1):

Despite: He had a great time, despite his initial pessimism.

Or, "The pie was good, despite the first, last, and every slice in between." (added for levity)